# Laravel 8 insert done wrong in order to fetch correctly

Tags: laravel

I have a form in which I have some checkboxes, I intend to store from the form in the form of array,( but it's saving in phpmyadmin with square brackets and " " )like this: `["optionselected1","optionselected2"]`

when I try to fetch those values in a dashboard in a different page they don't appear, I got this code:

create.blade

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="opt[]" value="opt1">opt1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="opt[]" value="opt2">opt2
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="sf[]" value="opt1">opt1
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="sf[]" value="opt2">opt2
    </label>
</div>
```

controller

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $opt= array($request->opt);
    $sf = array($request->sf);
    return view('admin.formulario.create', [
        'viaturas' => Viaturas::all(),
        'opt' => json_encode($opt),
        'sf' => json_encode($sf),
    ]);
}
```

store function

```
$data->opt= $request->input('opt');
$data->sf= $request->input('sf');
```

and in fetch page

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($formulario as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->opt}}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->sf}}</td>
```

How do I fetch correctly?

thanks in advance

Comment: Checkboxes won't be submitted when not checked, and also it makes no sense to have multiple checkboxes with the same name, i would use a radio button instead

Comment: i dont know if youre meaning to put it on the code on create . blade after value : checked. or if you mean check them on the form and submit it because it if is this last one ive already tried and its not working

Comment: i mean that when you don't check the checkboxes on the browser, you don't get a value on the store method, which might not be what you expect, it's looks like you are always expecting those opt and sf fields. If that's the case you should add an input hidden with your default value in it, before the checkbox, and with the same name, so when the checkbox   is not checked, your input is submitted instead